# if $_GET == $lang multi-lingual page changes

Tags: php, html

This select form it loads the right domain, page and language variable when clicked. But when a user changes the language two times in a row the url has two language variables. Example: 
domain.com/page.php?lang=en_us?lang=nl_be

How do I prevent this?

```
<div class="country_selector"><?php echo $lang['REGION']; ?>
        <select id="source" onchange="navigateTo(this, 'window', false);">
            <option value="https://domain.cc<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?lang=en_eu">Europa</option>
            <option value="https://domain.be<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?lang=nl_be">België</option>
            <option  value="https://domain.nl<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?lang=nl_nl">Nederland</option>
            <option  value="https://domain.uk<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?lang=en_uk">United Kingdom</option>
            <option  value="https://domain.cc<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?lang=en_us">United States</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add code of `navigateTo` function.

Comment: *"page.php?lang=en_us?lang=nl_be"* -- the first `?` separates the script name from the query string. The second `?` does not have any special meaning. The value of `$_GET['lang']` is `'en_us?lang=nl_be'`. Most probably not what you're expecting.

Comment: @Sougata Can you point me at the right direction for doing that? I'm quite new to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` includes the query string. Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead.

---

Another option, if you have more parameters in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` that you want to preserve in the generated URLs is to write a function that analyzes `$_GET[]` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, adds or replaces the `lang` parameter and generates the URL:

```
function generateLanguageURL(array $params, $lang)
{
    // Add the language to $params (or replace it if it's already there)
    $params['lang'] = $lang;

    // Generate the query string, append it to the script's URI and return
    // Generate partial URLs. There is no need to put the protocol
    // and the host name in the URL if they are the same as of the current page.
    return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.http_build_query($params);
}
```

The first argument (`array $params`) lets you use `$_GET` to generate URLs that contain all parameters of the current query string, `array()` to generate URLs without other parameters or any other combination of parameters you need (e.g. `array('q' => 'foo', 'items' => 10, 'page' => 2)`).

How to use it:

```
<div class="country_selector"><?php echo $lang['REGION']; ?>
    <select id="source" onchange="navigateTo(this, 'window', false);">
        <option value="<?php echo generateLanguageUrl($_GET, 'en_eu'); ?>">Europa</option>
        <option value="<?php echo generateLanguageUrl($_GET, 'nl_be'); ?>">België</option>
        <option value="<?php echo generateLanguageUrl($_GET, 'nl_nl'); ?>">Nederland</option>
        <option value="<?php echo generateLanguageUrl($_GET, 'en_uk'); ?>">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="<?php echo generateLanguageUrl($_GET, 'en_us'); ?>">United States</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

You can improve the function to let it generate any URL you need for your site by also adding the script path, the hostname and the protocol as optional arguments, using the values of the current page as defaults.

Comment: I tried that before. The problem is that all the content is dynamically generated from the index.php there are no other pages in the root. Basicly $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returns index.php on all the pages.
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] works perfect in this case, I only need to work around for rewriting the url

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for this for hours. I still have one question of which I can't find an answer. When for example, I am on this page: domain.com/?page=contact and the language has to be changed it has to be done like this: domain.com/?page=contact&lang=nl_be.
But currently it gets passed like this ?lang=nl_be, how can I make the ? change to & in the right situation? I tried google, but I have no clue how to search for that specific problem.

Comment: It's easier to generate the new URLs using `$_GET` as it contains the query string already parsed into parameters. Or you can manually parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` (it does not contain the `?`). However, if you need to parse a complete URL (or an arbitrary string) you can use the PHP [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php): [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the position of `?`, [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to extract a substring, [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) a.s.o.